# Openni2 problem with 2 xtion cameras

Tags: openni, xtion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody

I'm wanting to activate 2 xtion cameras with openni2 using ROS. One of the cameras works well and it shows the image (I do it checking with rqt), however, the other one is always showing a message telling:

```
Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data...
[ INFO] [1452532881.196199692]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason:

openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Device::OpenNI2Device(const string&) @ /tmp/buildd/ros-indigo-openni2-camera-0.2.5-0trusty-20151111-0829/src/openni2_device.cpp @ 74 : Device open failed
    Could not open "1d27/0601@2/3": USB transfer timeout!
```

...And of course in rqt it doesn't show anything.

Is there any limitation about using these 2 cameras at the same time? Do you have any clues about why this thing happened?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223848/openni2-problem-with-2-xtion-cameras/) by [Diego](https://answers.ros.org/users/21507/diego/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2016-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I already solved the problem but not in the way I wanted. The system can support 2 cameras, however disconnecting and connecting is not the most professional option (since the camera was recognized by the computer port) if someone has already experienced this thing, I would be glad to know how to solve it.

---

Originally posted by [Diego](https://answers.ros.org/users/21507/diego/) with karma: 46 on 2016-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-01-18**:
You should be able to programmatically tell linux to reset a given usb device which ought to be identical to a physical replug, though there is some amount of troublesome navigation of a usb tree to find the right usb location.  I might have more info later or if you find out something post it here